# how to scroll top and bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Wrapper").click(function () {
var th = $(this);
if (!th.hasClass('down')) {
    console.log("ret");
    th.addClass('down').stop(true).animate({
        "top": "50px"
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('body').scrollTop(th.height());
    });
} else {
    console.log("sdffsdsff");
    th.removeClass('down').stop(true).animate({
        "top": "-400px"
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('body').scrollTop(th.scrollTop());
    });
}
```

});
});

I have this jquery code for scroll from top to bottom and bottom to top when click on wrapper. this code works but i want this should scroll slowly from top top bottom and bottom to top when click on "wrapper" div

this is my original fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HtTXB/17/

how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#Wrapper").click(function () {
  var h= $(this).height(),
      top= $(window).scrollTop(),
      pos= top > h/2 ? 0 : h;

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: pos
  },1000);
});
```

`scrollTop` is set to 0 when the window is scrolled more than half-way, and it's set to the height of `Wrapper` when scrolled less than half-way.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pywcprmw/)**